# arraylist->cap in arraylist_append function make no sense

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to programm my own dynamic sized array system. But the array->cap values that are stored in the arraylist_append function make absolutely no sense. I guessing I have a buffer overflow, but I could not find it.
array.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct arraylist_meta {
    size_t len, cap, sizeof_one_element;
};

void* arraylist_create(size_t array_size, size_t sizeof_one_element) {
    struct arraylist_meta *arraylist_new = malloc(array_size * sizeof_one_element + sizeof*arraylist_new);
    printf("Created array at %p\n", arraylist_new);
    arraylist_new->len = array_size;
    arraylist_new->cap = array_size;
    arraylist_new->sizeof_one_element = sizeof_one_element;
    printf("Sizeof arraylist_meta %zd\n", sizeof(struct arraylist_meta));
    return arraylist_new+1;
}

void* arraylist_append(void *arraylist_void, void *element_void) {
    char *element = element_void;
    struct arraylist_meta *arraylist = arraylist_void;
    --arraylist;
    printf("appending at array with address %p\n", arraylist);
    printf("arraylist len: %zd\narraylist cap: %zd\n", arraylist->len, arraylist->cap);
    if(arraylist->len == arraylist->cap) {
        arraylist->cap = arraylist->len + 10;
        arraylist = realloc(arraylist, arraylist->cap * arraylist->sizeof_one_element + sizeof *arraylist);
        printf("Realloc array. new address %p\n", arraylist);
    }
    char *arraylist_char = (char*)arraylist+1;
    arraylist_char += arraylist->sizeof_one_element * arraylist->len;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < arraylist->sizeof_one_element; ++arraylist_char, ++element, ++i) {
        *arraylist_char = *element;
    }
    ++arraylist->len;
    return arraylist+1;
}
```

array.h

```
#ifndef array_h
#define array_h
void* arraylist_create(size_t array_size, size_t sizeof_one_element);
void* arraylist_append(void *arraylist_void, void *element_void);
#endif
```

A little test programm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "array.h"

int main() {
    int *int_array = arraylist_create(2, sizeof (int));
    int_array[0] = 28;
    int_array[1] = 20;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) int_array = arraylist_append(int_array, &i);
    for(int i = 0; i < 102; ++i) printf("Index: %d Value: %d\n", i, int_array[i]);
}
```

If I run it get the following ouput

```
Created array at 0x55cfba2962a0
Sizeof arraylist_meta 24
appending at array with address 0x55cfba2962a0
arraylist len: 2
arraylist cap: 2
Realloc array. new address 0x55cfba2966e0
appending at array with address 0x55cfba2966e0
arraylist len: 3
arraylist cap: 12
appending at array with address 0x55cfba2966e0
arraylist len: 4
arraylist cap: 1099511627788
appending at array with address 0x55cfba2966e0
arraylist len: 5
arraylist cap: 1099511627788
...
appending at array with address 0x55cfba2966e0
arraylist len: 101
arraylist cap: 1099511627788

Index: 0 Value: 28
Index: 1 Value: 20
Index: 2 Value: 0
...
Index: 11 Value: 0
Index: 12 Value: 133345
Index: 13 Value: 0
...
Index: 101 Value: 0
```

As you can see the arraylist->cap values are unexpectedly high

Comment: You could run https://drmemory.org/ on your program to detect the overflow. It is straight forward to install and run

Comment: Welcome to SO. As it is rather obvious that the values start getting weird very soon after you start appending to the array. No need to flood fill the post with prints for 100 append operation when you can see the error already after 2 or 3 calls.

Comment: This line seems wrong: `struct arraylist_meta *arraylist_new = malloc(array_size * sizeof_one_element + sizeof*arraylist_new);` Shouldn't it be: `struct arraylist_meta *arraylist_new = malloc(array_size * sizeof_one_element + sizeof(arraylist_meta );`

Comment: @Jean-MarcVolle Not really. First of all, there is no type `arraylist_meta` it must be `struct arraylist_meta`. Besides that `*arraylist_new` is of type `struct arraylist_meta` which does not make any difference in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with operator precedence in C:

```
char *arraylist_char = (char*)arraylist+1;
```

The type cast has higher precedence than the `+` operator.

This means, you first cast to a `char*` and then add `+1`.
This will point to 1 byte after start of the header.

you can check this by adding these prints:

```
printf("arrylist: %p\n", (void*)arraylist);
printf("arrylist+1: %p\n", (void*)(arraylist+1));
printf("(char*)arrylist+1: %p\n", (void*)((char*)arraylist+1));
printf("(char*)(arrylist+1): %p\n", (void*)((char*)(arraylist+1)));
```

Which results in this output:

```
appending at array with address 0x55ecf3a3e260
arraylist len: 2
arraylist cap: 2
Realloc array. new address 0x55ecf3a3e6a0
arrylist: 0x55ecf3a3e6a0
arrylist+1: 0x55ecf3a3e6b8
(char*)arrylist+1: 0x55ecf3a3e6a1   <<=== WRONG!
(char*)(arrylist+1): 0x55ecf3a3e6b8 <<=== CORRECT
```

What you want is add the size of the whole header struct. To do this, add bracket:

```
char *arraylist_char = (char*)(arraylist+1);
```

Besides this bug, your code has additional problems:

1. `arraylist = realloc(arraylist,...`

   You should never assign the return value from realloc to the pointer you feed into the function. In case of an error, NULL is returned and you have lost the old value of the pointer.
2. Your approach is not safe for all types. It is possible that you run into problems with alignment on some architectures. If the data type to be stored in that array has an alignment restriction that is larger than that of arraylist_meta which is basically same as the aligment for size_t, the returned pointer might not be properly aligned for the stored data type.

   As an example you could think about a machine where `size_t` is only 4 bytes resulting in a size for your header of 12 bytes in total with alignment 4 bytes.  Now lets assume you want to store a struct with some large data type, lets say `long double` which might have an alignment requirement of 8 bytes. While `malloc` and `realloc` normalle return a pointer that is aligned to meet the lartest alignment requirement for the architecture, adding 12 bytes for the header will result in a pointer that does not fullfil requirement for 8 bytes needed by the stored struct. You should enlarge that header size to meet the largest alignment needs of your architecture or to meet size of stored elements at least.

   One option to do this would look like this:
   The union should cause the proper alignment for the larger data types included.

```
    union arraylist_meta {
        double dummy_double;
        long double dummy_long_double;
        long long dummy_long_long;
        void *dummy_ptr;
        void (*dummy_func_ptr)(void);
        struct {
            size_t len;
            size_t cap;
            size_t sizeof_one_element;
        };
    };
```

Or even a bit more elegant if you use C11 (as MrGeorgen found out):

```
    #include <stddef.h>
    struct arraylist_meta {
        union {
            max_align_t dummy;
            struct {
                size_t len;
                size_t cap;
                size_t sizeof_one_element;
            };
        };
    };
```

This is more generic to get the largest possible alignment and I added an additional level of nesting in a struct. That allows keeping the data types in function declarations and existing callers of effected functions.

Comment: thanks for your helpfull respone, but is there a way to enlarge the header size to meet the largest alignment for all architectures

Comment: I am not 100% sure if that helps for all architectures but you can see a suggestion in my update

Comment: A simple way, which not quite memory efficient would be to use the dummy type [max_align_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/max_align_t) as you can below

Comment: sorry at the time I wrote this, I did not understand what an union actually is.

Comment: No problem. Your solution seems more elegant. Didn't know that type.

Comment: the only disadvantage is this type was in C11, but this is not a problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to the alignment problem

```
#include <stddef.h>
union arraylist_meta {
        max_align_t dummy;
        struct {
            size_t len;
            size_t cap;
            size_t sizeof_one_element;
        };
    }
```

The max_align_t is actually a struct with the gcc compiler. It looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
  long long __max_align_ll __attribute__((__aligned__(__alignof__(long long))));
  long double __max_align_ld __attribute__((__aligned__(__alignof__(long double))));
  /* _Float128 is defined as a basic type, so max_align_t must be
     sufficiently aligned for it.  This code must work in C++, so we
     use __float128 here; that is only available on some
     architectures, but only on i386 is extra alignment needed for
     __float128.  */
#ifdef __i386__
  __float128 __max_align_f128 __attribute__((__aligned__(__alignof(__float128))));
#endif
} max_align_t;
```

I have idea why struct is used there. Probably this type represents only the maximum alginment, but not the maximum size of a base type. So the solution  Gerhardh came up with earlier is actually better, because max_align_t is unnecessarily large.
Another possibility is to use the `__attribute__((__aligned__` as you can see above at the type definition of the `max_align_t`. The problem is these attributes are not defined by any C standart

Comment: Good solution. On my system I get sizeof 24 for the initial struct and 32 for `max_align_t`.  But ....I have no idea what data type might require 32 bytes... ;)

Comment: I have looked a bit into the stddef.h header and the max_align_t is a structur as can see above